# Adding mcrypt to Plesk

Tags: php, plesk, mcrypt

I am running Plesk v8.2.0 and I have a program that needs mcrypt module installed but I cant find any relevent infromation on how to get mcrypt setup on Plesk. It is on a Unix based server.

Does anyone have any ideas on how to set this up?

Any infromation would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 3):

From command line, do something like...

`yum install php-mcrypt.x86_64`

If that doesn't work, then maybe do...

```
yum search "mcrypt"
```

.. to find the exact name of the file you want to install.

Comment: I thought the same thing, but in the opposite order. I tried searching for the package exactly as you describe, and oddly enough it does not show up in the results. The package is in YUM and I can install it, but using `yum search "mcrypt"` did not display it!

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the OS. I don't think Plesk has a module or a drop-in solution for mcrypt.

You might find more answers at [serverfault](http://serverfault.com).

https://serverfault.com/questions/60787/howto-make-mcrypt-and-php-work-together-on-centos

Answer (score 1):

Mcrypt is a PHP module, and typically you can download this in some kind of package format.

On RedHat, CentOS, or Fedora, I would suggest using the IUS repository. Otherwise you can look for the distribution, and php-mcrypt and there is likely a package available for it. If not, you can always compile it from source: http://www.php.net/manual/en/mcrypt.installation.php

If you do compile it from source, be sure to set php on the skip list (RPM-based distribution) so that it is not updated automatically, as that will break it's functionality, until it is recompiled.